# Trouble with Regex matching

Tags: regex

How would I tell Regex to match everything except for the middle "foo", because it is the only instance where "foo" appears completely on it's own and is not part of another word?

bar foo foobar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this homework????

`/(?!\bfoo\b)\b\w+/g`

Comment: no, just the result of me trying for an hour and not being able to figure it out! Thank you very much!! :]